# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() with PHP 7 and SQL 2016 Express

Tags: php, sql-server

I have read a few posts referring to older versions of PHP and MS SQL connectivity but does not seem able to help me with my similar issue.

I am running...
Windows Server 2012
PHP 7.09
MS SQL 2016 Express

I have installed the following drivers from Microsoft
php7.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
(Microsoft seems to have published 2 different versions on Microsoft and github respectively. I have tried both versions)
I am using fastcgi so believe it is in order to use nts version of dll allthough MS claims either would work with fastcgi.

MICROSOFT ODBC Driver V13 for SQL 2016 installed (automatically installs with MS SQL 2016 installation/so does sqlcli.dll)

I am referencing the correct PHP.INI. I hope?

Loaded Configuration File  - Shows correct directory
Configuration File (php.ini) Path  - Shows c:\windows (Why? Do I need to change this? I am not sure what the php.ini in the Windows directory is for.)
My extensions_dir is correct and PHP Admin in IIS shows that the above drivers are enabled

This is what is not happening which indicates that SQL Drivers are not working....
SQLSRV section does not display in phpinfo.
As far as I know that means the drivers are not registered.

Please can anyone assist or shed some light?

Thank you.